# i cant understand whats wrong with my code i get logged if i enter any of the users passwords

Tags: python

this my login function

```
import getpass
import warnings
import csv
import time

admin={"Evan":"1234","Nirmal":"4567","admin":"1729"}
manager={"Max":"7785","Jack":"5648",'Alan':'5464'}
standard={"Smith":"2548","Virat":"1818",'Steve':'5487'}

scheduled={'MH370':["10:10",'Delhi',"Delayed"],'KI784':['1:20','Pune','Delayed'],
           'PH169':['12:20','Seattle','Scheduled'],'BH234':['15:20','Bangalore','Scheduled'],
           'PH234':['15:00','Prayagraj','Delayed'],'BT452':['18:30','Malaysia','Scheduled'],
           'KR234':['15:20','Cuba','Scheduled']}

cancelled={'AI169':["11:30","Bombay","Cancelled"]}

def login(u):
  q=2

  while q==2:
    warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

    try :
        uid=u
        
        upwd=getpass.getpass(prompt="Enter the User Password : -\t")

        if uid in admin or uid in manager or uid in standard:
            found=1

        else:
            found=0

        if upwd in admin.get(uid) or upwd in manager.get(uid) or upwd in standard.get(uid):
            found=1

        else:
            found=0
            
    except:
        print("")

    if found==0:
        time.sleep(1)
        print("\n... Entered User Name  / Password is wrong ...")
        
    else:
        time.sleep(1)
        print("\n System Starting.... \a\a\a\a\a\a")
        break
```

if I type Evan as the username and type any of the passwords in the admin dictionary(1234,4567,1729) I get logged in. Here's the full code

```
import getpass
import warnings
import csv
import time

admin={"Evan":"1234","Nirmal":"4567","admin":"1729"}
manager={"Max":"7785","Jack":"5648",'Alan':'5464'}
standard={"Smith":"2548","Virat":"1818",'Steve':'5487'}

scheduled={'MH370':["10:10",'Delhi',"Delayed"],'KI784':['1:20','Pune','Delayed'],
           'PH169':['12:20','Seattle','Scheduled'],'BH234':['15:20','Bangalore','Scheduled'],
           'PH234':['15:00','Prayagraj','Delayed'],'BT452':['18:30','Malaysia','Scheduled'],
           'KR234':['15:20','Cuba','Scheduled']}

cancelled={'AI169':["11:30","Bombay","Cancelled"]}

#This function is responsible for shlowing all the users

def view_users():
    admin1=list(admin.keys())
    manager1=list(manager.keys())
    standard1=list(standard.keys())
    print("Admins are :- ",admin1)
    print("Managers are :- ",manager1)
    print("Standard Users are :- ",standard1)
    
#This function is responsible for deleting users

def delete_user_account():
    user=input("Enter the username to be deleted : -\t")
    time.sleep(1)

    if not(user in admin or user in manager or user in standard):
        print("Username not found")

    else:

        if user=="admin":
            print("Cannot delete main admin")

        elif user in admin.keys():

            if user!="admin":
                del admin[user]
                print("Admin user successfully deleted")

        elif user in manager.keys():
            del manager[user]
            print("Manager user successfully deleted")

        elif user in standard.keys():
            del standard[user]
            print("Standard user successfully deleted")

        else:
            pass

#this function is responsible for adding admin
        
def add_admin():
    user=input("Enter the username to be added : -\t")
    time.sleep(1)

    if user in admin or user in manager or user in standard:
        print("Username already exists")

    else:
        password=input("Enter the password : -\t")
        time.sleep(1)
        admin[user]=password
        print("Admin successfully added")

#this function is responsible for adding manager
        
def add_manager():
    user=input("Enter the username to be added : -\t")
    time.sleep(1)

    if user in admin or user in manager or user in standard:
        print("Username already exists,try again")

    else:
        password=input("Enter the password : -\t")
        time.sleep(1)
        manager[user]=password
        print("Manager successfully added")

#this function is responsible for adding standard user
        
def add_standard():
    user=input("Enter the username to be added : -\t")
    time.sleep(1)
    
    if user in admin or user in manager or user in standard:
        print("Username already exists,try again")

    else:
        password=input("Enter the password : -\t")
        time.sleep(1)
        standard[user]=password
        print("Standard user successfully added")

#this function is responsible for adding flights
        
def update_add_flights():
    choice1=input("Do you want to schedule a new flight(Y,N) : -\t")

    if choice1 in ("Y","y"):
        name=input("Enter the name of the flight : -\t")

        if name in scheduled:
            print("Flight already added")
            update_add_flights()

        else:
            time=input("Enter the departure time : -\t")
            dest=input("Enter the flight destination : -\t")
            stat=input("Enter flight status : -\t")

            scheduled[name]=[time,dest,stat]
            print("Flight ",name,"successfully added")
    else:
      choice2=input("Do you want to update existing flight information(Y,N) : -\t")

      if choice2 in ("Y","y"):
        name=input("Enter the name of the flight : -\t")

        if name in scheduled:
            time=input("Enter the departue time : -\t")
            dest=input("Enter the flight destination : -\t")
            stat=input("Enter flight status : -\t")
            
            del scheduled[name]
            scheduled[name]=[time,dest,stat]
            print("Flight updated")

        else:
            print("No flight by this name")

#this function is responsible for cancelling flights
            
def cancel_flights():
    name=input("Enter name of flight : -\t")
    time.sleep(1)

    if name in cancelled:
        print("Flight already cancelled")

    elif name in scheduled:
        n=scheduled.get(name)
        del scheduled[name]
        cancelled[name]=n
        print("Flight cancelled")

    else:
        print("Flight not found,please try again")

#this function is responsible for viewing flights
        
def view_flights():
    print()
    print("Scheduled Flights")
    print()
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Flight Number",'%12s'% 'ETA','%25s'% 'Destination','%25s'% "Status")
    time.sleep(1)
    print()
    for i in scheduled:
        print(i, '%25s'%scheduled[i][0], '%25s'%scheduled[i][1], '%25s'%scheduled[i][2])
        time.sleep(1)

    print()
    print()

    print("Cancelled Flights")
    print()
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Flight Number",'%12s'% 'ETA','%25s'% 'Destination','%25s'% "Status")
    time.sleep(1)
    print()

    for j in cancelled:
        print(j, '%25s'%cancelled[j][0], '%25s'%cancelled[j][1], '%25s'%cancelled[j][2])
        time.sleep(1)


#admin control panel
        
def admins():
  q=1

  while q==1:
    command=int(input('''
To view details of flight    press 1
To add/update a flight     press 2
To cancel a flight             press 3
To manage users             press 4

Press any other key to exit
 : - '''))

    if command==1:
        view_flights()

    elif command==2:
        update_add_flights()

    elif command==3:
        cancel_flights()

    elif command==4:
            print()
            print()
            command2=int(input('''
To add users             press 1
To delete users         press 2
To view users           press 3

Press any other key to return to control panel
 : - '''))
            time.sleep(1)
            print()
            print()

            if command2==1:
                command3=int(input('''
To add admin user           press 1
To add manager user       press 2
To add standard user       press 3

To return to contol panel press any other value
: - '''))
                print()
                time.sleep(1)
                
                if command3==1:
                        add_admin()

                elif command3==2:
                        add_manager()

                elif command3==3:
                        add_standard()

                else:
                        print('''Returning to control panel''')
                        time.sleep(1)

            elif command2==2:
                delete_user_account()

            elif command2==3:
                view_users()
                
            else:
                print()

    else:
        break

#manager control panel
    
def managers():
  q=1

  while q==1:
    time.sleep(1)
    command=int(input('''
To view details of flight      press 1
To add/update a flight       press 2
To cancel a flight               press 3
To manage users               press 4

Press any other key to exit
: - '''))
    time.sleep(1)
    print()

    if command==1:
        view_flights()

    elif command==2:
        update_add_flights()

    elif command==3:
        cancel_flights()

    elif command==4:
            command2=int(input('''
To add users        press 1
To delete users    press 2
To view users      press 3

Press any other key to return to control panel
: - '''))
            print()
            time.sleep(1)

            if command2==1:
                command3=int(input('''
To add manager user        press 1
To add standard user        press 2

To return to contol panel press any other value
: - '''))
                print()
                time.sleep(1)

                if command3==1:
                        add_manager()

                elif command3==2:
                        add_standard()

                else:
                        print('''Returning to control panel''')

            elif command2==2:
                delete_user_account()

            elif command2==3:
                view_users()
                
            else:
                print()

    else:
        break
    
#standard user control panel
    
def standards():
  q=1

  while q==1:
    time.sleep(1)
    command=int(input('''
To view details of flight       press 1
To view users                      press 2

Press any other number to exit
: - '''))
    print()
    time.sleep(1)

    if command==1:
        view_flights()

    elif command==2:
        view_users()
        
    else:
        break
    
#login function

def login(u):
  q=2

  while q==2:
    warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

    try :
        uid=u
        
        upwd=getpass.getpass(prompt="Enter the User Password : -\t")

        if uid in admin or uid in manager or uid in standard:
            found=1

        else:
            found=0

        if upwd in admin.get(uid) or upwd in manager.get(uid) or upwd in standard.get(uid):
            found=1

        else:
            found=0
            
    except:
        print("")

    if found==0:
        time.sleep(1)
        print("\n... Entered User Name  / Password is wrong ...")
        
    else:
        time.sleep(1)
        print("\n System Starting.... \a\a\a\a\a\a")
        break

time.sleep(1)
username=input("Enter Username : -\t")

login(username)

time.sleep(1)
if username in admin:
    admins()

elif username in manager:
    managers()

elif username in standard:
    standards()

else:
    pass
```

this is a flight management program i had created for my school project. I am new to python and this our first project. can anyone pls help.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ is a great place to start for solving this. Put `print()` functions in your code, including the exception part (you can capture and print the actual exception, if any, as `except Exception as exc: print(exc)`).

Comment: You should be more specific about what is the error you are seeing. Narrow it down to a short section of code. Also, the `try ... except:` block is going to mask all errors remove that so you can see if there are any errors in there.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want something like this instead of your two if statements:

```py
admins = {'a': '123', 'b': '345', 'c': ' 678'}

uid = 'a'
pwd = '123'
if uid in admins and pwd == admins.get(uid):
    print('Logged in')
else:
    print('Wrong username or password.')
```